# javascript bootstrap-multiselect get all selected values on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get all selected values of `bootstrap-multiselect` on button click.

My JSP page code is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ddlPermission').multiselect({
            buttonWidth : '100%',
            maxHeight : 100,
            includeSelectAllOption : true,
            dropRight : true
        });
    });

    function myFunction() {
        var allVal=$("ddlPermission").val();
        alert(allVal);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <select id="ddlPermission" multiple="multiple" name="permission_ddl">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="myFunction()" class="button active" value="Submit">
</body>
```

I am using Java JSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vg6oLvxo/264/).**

You're missing the id sign `#` in the following line :

```
var allVal=$("ddlPermission").val();
```

Should be :

```
var allVal=$("#ddlPermission").val();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(){

    var selectedText = [];
    var selectedValues = [];
    $('#ddlPermission :selected').each(function(i, value){ 
        selectedValues[i] = value; 
        selectedText[i] = $(value).text(); 

    });

});
```

selectedValues array will contain all the values of the selected options,

selectedText array will contain all the text of the selected options